# Unprecise Results when dividing two numbers

Tags: matlab, division, rounding-error

I stumbled upon some weird MATLAB behavior while running a unit test. I do receive some "incorrect" or "unprecise" results when computing the percentage change of two data points. For illustrative purpose, take a look at the following example.

```
test1 = 101/100-1             % test1 = 0.01
tf1 = isequal(test1, 0.01)    % tf1 = false
```

On my machine `tf1`is `false`, which is clearly wrong as `test1` should exactly be equal to `0.01`. In the first place I thought this might have something to do with the division resulting in a "rounding" error.
However, if you avoid the substraction (-1) in the first place, `tf` becomes `true`.

```
test2 = 101/100               % test2 = 1.01
tf2 = isequal(test2, 1.01)    % tf2 = true
```

Now, I am a bit confused and I am wondering what is going on?

Comment: Change format to `format longe`. Now run `101/100-1`, and then run `0.01` See if these are equal or not. Read the duplicate target for details